# Change geta not found handler redirect type default

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm using geta-notFoundHandler, and I was wondering if it is possible to change the default redirect type from Temporary to Permanent. I know it is possible to just change it with the dropdown when creating a new redirect URL, but i want it to be Permanent by default.

I already went throught their github repo, but without any success. This is my getaNotFoundHandler module:
`

```
public class GetaNotFoundHandlerModule : FeatureModule
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString;

        public GetaNotFoundHandlerModule(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Enabled = Enabled ?? true;
            _connectionString = configuration.GetConnectionString("EPiServerDB");
        }

        public override void ConfigureServices(ServiceContext context)
        {
            context.Services.AddNotFoundHandler(options =>
            {
                options.UseSqlServer(_connectionString);
                options.HandlerMode = FileNotFoundMode.On;
                options.Logging = LoggerMode.Off;
                options.AddProvider<LegacyFundDetailRedirectHandler>();
                options.AddProvider<CultureProfileRedirectHandler>();
            });
            context.Services.AddOptimizelyNotFoundHandler();
        }

        public override void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            base.Configure(app);

            app.UseNotFoundHandler();
        }

        public override void ConfigureWebRoutes(IEndpointRouteBuilder routes)
        {
            base.ConfigureWebRoutes(routes);

            routes.MapRazorPages();
        }
    }
```

I'm using this version:

```
<PackageReference Include="Geta.NotFoundHandler.Optimizely" Version="5.0.8" />
```

this is their github repo:
https://github.com/Geta/geta-notfoundhandler/

Comment: I would ask on their repo

Comment: @DanielA.White did asked the question over there as well, but I also gave it try over here. Thanks for you advice anyways!